# Issue with C++ conditional statement causing unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, if-statement, data-structures

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"

using namespace std;

vector<int> findMedian(vector<int> &arr, int n) {
    priority_queue<int> maxheap; // Store smaller elements (left half)
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minheap; // Store larger elements (right half)
    vector<int> medians;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        maxheap.push(arr[i]);

        // Ensure smaller elements are in the maxheap 
        if (minheap.size() > 0 && maxheap.top() > minheap.top()) {
            minheap.push(maxheap.top());
            maxheap.pop();
        }

        // Maintain a balance between sizes of the two heaps
        if (minheap.size() > maxheap.size() + 1) {
            maxheap.push(minheap.top());
            minheap.pop();
        } else if (maxheap.size() > minheap.size() + 1) {
            minheap.push(maxheap.top());
            maxheap.pop();
        }

        // Calculate the median based on whether the total count of elements is even or odd
        if ((minheap.size() + maxheap.size()) % 2 == 0) {
            medians.push_back((minheap.top() + maxheap.top()) / 2); 
        } else { // Implied 'else' here since the size difference can't be more than 1
            if (maxheap.size() > minheap.size()) {
                medians.push_back(maxheap.top());
            } else { // Must be minheap.size() > maxheap.size() 
                medians.push_back(minheap.top());
            }
        }
    }

    return medians;
}
```

but if i change these 2 line of code to
`if (maxHeap.size() - minHeap.size() > 1)` and
`else if (minHeap.size() - maxHeap.size() > 1)` then the code give a runtime error of SIGSEGV even though these 2 lines of code are mathematically equivalent.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `size()` returns an unsigned value

Comment: For sizes do not use `int`, use `std::size_t`.  Side notes : `#include "bits/stdc++.h"` NO (it is not standard C++), `using namespace std;` NO it is not recommended. Replace your include with includes <queue>, <vector> and the like

Comment: consider this simpler example https://godbolt.org/z/fx7Mh7955

Comment: `#include "bits/stdc++.h"` loads the gun by including the tens of thousands of identifiers in The C++ Standard Library. `using namespace std;` Takes off the safety by pulling all of those identifiers into the global namespace where they will come into conflict with your code. This makes it very easy to shoot yourself in the foot, so be extremely cautious.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Comment: I also recommend you read [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: *Am I missing something?*  Yes, those two lines are not mathematically equivalent, because of unsigned modulo 2 wrap around.

Comment: When in doubt, print stuff out. If you print `maxHeap.size() - minHeap.size()` and `minHeap.size() - maxHeap.size()`, you may not know why the results are different, but you will see that the results are different. And odds are good that when you see the number and perform a few quick experiments, you'd recognize you were looking at a number around a maximum unsigned integer and would probably figure out what had happened on your own.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why not sort the vector then return the middle item?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] even though these 2 lines of code are mathematically equivalent

They are not.

[`std::vector::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns `std::vector::size_type` which is an unsigned type. Unsigned integers cannot be negative. If you subtract a larger unsigned value from a smaller one the result is not negative, but it wraps around. `0U - 1U` is the maximum unsigned value.

The following code prints the same value 3 times:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>


int main(){
    std::vector<int> x{1};
    std::vector<int> y{};

    std::cout << y.size()-x.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::vector<int>::size_type>::max() << "\n";
    std::cout << 0LU - 1LU;
}
```

(the third could be different, depending on width of  `std::vector<int>::size_type`)

Thats the reason the two lines are not the same. A common workaround is what you did in your working code, to rewrite the expression in a way that avoids the wrap around:

```
if (minheap.size() > maxheap.size() + 1) ...
```

This can still fail, when `+1` makes `maxheap.size()` wrap around (ie when `maxheap.size()` is the maximum value `std::vector<int>::size_type` can represent). However, that is much less likely than one container having more elements than the other.

Just for the sake of completeness I mention `std::ssize` that returns a signed value available since C++20.